# How to access SwiftUI documentation for iOS16

Tags: swiftui

In the SwiftUI Apple docs for managing data (for example) at:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app
I can see the beta docs for iOS17.
How (where) can I read the documentation for iOS16?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

Comment: All of the documentation is at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui. You just happened to show a part of the documentation for a new API that does not exist in iOS 16.

Comment: my question is how to get to the `iOS16` documentation, not the `iOS17`.
 The link I show is an example, that I know has iOS16 documentation,
 **it does exist**, and it dealt specifically with `ObservableObject`.
There are many other links that now only refers only to iOS17,  how can I read this documentation for the **current** iOS16 not the next iOS17 beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 14, under Window->Developer Documentation

Comment: is there a way to get that info through the browser? so that for example, I can refer other people to it.

Comment: surprisingly using Xcode 15 also gives the iOS16 documentation (ObservableObject),
 only the browser does not.